# Error on calling plugins/index.js to Cypress 10 version

Tags: configuration, cypress

I am trying to import plugins/index.js to the new structure of Cypress 10 but unfortunately it is not working.

[image]

File Structure:
[image]

Comment: Can you add your `cypress.config.js` file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like the folder structure is a little bit different to the out-of-the-box setup.

Based on the paths shown in the screenshot, I would guess you need to adjust the line with the error to

```js
return require('../../../cypress/plugins/index.js`)
```

If it's still not working, take a look at the file structure to see what relative path is needed.

If still can't get it, post the file structure of the project up in the question.

Comment: I am trying to call the cypress/plugins/index.js (Folder Dir from the old Cypress version) to import it to the cypress.config.js

Comment: Yes, but the message "Cannot find module" means the path is wrong. Did you have any luck adjusting the path as I suggested?

Comment: I edited the post with file structure image

Comment: You gave a different screenshot  - the first needs 3 `../` but the second needs only 2 `../`.

Comment: Thank you, I can run the test but encountered a new one wherein 'task' should be declared on setupNodeEvents. I will close this ticket and work on the new issue